# Apache 2 - reload config on Windows

Tags: windows, apache2, httpd.conf

I have a PHP script that modifies my httpd.conf file, so I need to automatically reload it in Apache.

On Linux, there is graceful restart, but on Windows (I use the restart command) it terminates all the current connections. Is there a command as graceful restart on Windows? Is there a workaround on this?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you should use the -k switch.

```
   httpd.exe -k restart or apache.exe -k restart
```

More info here has well. http://www.zrinity.com/developers/apache/usage.cfm

**Edit:**

It shouldn't that is the point of **Graceful**. Notice I used the `-k`. That is not the same as a normal restart. It let's the current sessions complete their task while the config is being reread, so that it will start taking new requests immediately.

From the documentation:

*The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.*

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful

It's doing what you are asking for.

**Edit 2:**

Adding this link and gave both possible versions because some people think you there is only one specific way to do something instead of search themselves.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#wincons

***I think I'm just going to delete this answer because either people can't read or if it doesn't work for someone it gets a DV. There are different windows versions made by different developers. If it doesn't work look for the answer from them. Even Linux has different commands depending on the distro. geez***

Comment: I know how to restart Apache, but "restart" doesn't help me that much. It still closes the current connections on ports 80 and 443, so the users who happen to load a page a that time will get an error.

Comment: I tested it on Apache 2.2.22 some time ago. Sometimes (rarely) it just freezes the page loading process. But it mostly terminates the connection and the browser pops up the Unknown page error. Image that happening when some users are uploading stuff. On Linux, on the other hand, it works like a charm.

Comment: Well unfortunately we can only go by how **apache** says it's **supposed** to work. I have no doubt it works better on linux. I don't use apache on Windows, I only use Linux(CentOS) web servers personally. So I feel your pain but it could have been some other configuration issue or a bug previously. Not sure how it might work on windows now. That is the only way I know to do it on Windows however.

Comment: Down voted as the response doesn't address the user's *actual* question - how to perform a graceful restart on Windows.

Comment: @DaveG yes it does. I even provided a link. some versions used `Apache.exe` and some used `httpd.exe`. If you do that from a command prompt you don't need to use the extension in windows. **THAT'S** also why I provided the link. And it was also for example. The main clue was the -k option regardless of OS. Did you even bother to read? So that was a baseless downvote.

Comment: "It shouldn't that is the point of Graceful" -- this doesn't make sense. What shouldn't what?

"Adding this link and gave both possible versions because some people think you there is only one specific way to do something instead of search themselves" -- this isn't relevant and doesn't explain what the link is.

Comment: @Buster It does make since. I put Edit, because I answered the first comment if you bothered to read instead of foolishly down voting a legit answer. If you're unable to understand just ask? The link provides additional information and it's only purpose. There are different versions compiled by different projects which is why i listed both.

Comment: Be nice. I understand it perfectly, but this answer is not helpful as it stands.

Comment: @Buster apparently it helped 12 others who voted for it. The answer is at the very top, the rest was just supporting info. Not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: How to do this if you are NOT using service?

Answer (score 2):

In the newest Apache 2.4.20 VC10 the "httpd -k restart" command actually DOES do a graceful restart. It won't drop any connections, for example if somebody is downloading something from your server, it WILL NOT interrupt this process. One more proof is that "-k restart" will not reset your server statistics that mod_status provides, won't even alter the "Restart Time" value.

Although "httpd -k graceful" and "httpd -k graceful-stop" commands are available in Windows, but they will not work giving an error "couldn't make a socket".